# Spring 3 and JAXB in Web Services

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm trying to write a simple web service that automagically serializes and deserializes objects using JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SimpleObject {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    /* ... */
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class SimpleObjectController {

    @RequestMapping("submit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doPost(@RequestBody SimpleObject value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans ...>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" class="path.to.objects"/>
</beans>
```

When I actually make the request, however, I get the following:

```
HTTP Status 415
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not
supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().
```

I get no logs back from Spring, making it hard for me to determine the root cause. Is there a critical step in this process which I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is because of a missing Accept header or Content Type header of "application/xml" in your request. Also if you are using Spring 3.1, you can make your annotation even more explicit this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="submit",method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/xml", produces="application/xml")
```

Comment: Yep, I needed to modify my `curl` request as well: `curl -X POST -d "<content/>" -H "Content-Type:application/xml" http://localhost:9080/submit`. Forgot about how specific Spring was.